# Can AC and DC components both exists across the same point within the filter RC series network in parallel with the diode in the power supply?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Just an enquiry about measurement and getting both AC and DC values across the same point.
Let me introduce the measurement that How i have done to measure voltages across different components of the below power supply circuit.
[image]

Please look into the measurement data also to see what values I got during measurement.[image]

My doubt is when I measured between P211 to P202 I got both AC as well as DC and During measurement between nodes P211 to P202 only AC I got not DC (Why?)

Can AC as well as DC exist between P211 to P202?
If it exists what is the rationale if i could get that would be understandable to me. 
Note: DC values I measured with separate DC true RMS multimeter.

Thanks.

Comment: "During measurement between nodes P211 to P202 only AC I got not DC (Why?)" - what does this mean and sure, AC and DC signals can exist together at the same measurement point, it all depends on how you regard the composite signal mathematically. Also a DC voltmeter measures the average value not the RMS value so "DC true RMS multimeter" doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: Sorry Andy, Actually it was a typo I wanted to write "During measurement between nodes P211 to P202 I got both AC and DC as given in the second row of the measurement table.(After R201 to Pin 16)"                                                                But between nodes P212 to P202 I got only AC and not DC(After R202 to Pin 16), Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a two-switch forward converter. Here's the simplified schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Pj3F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

SW1 and SW2 are primary switches and they both open and close at the same time.

When SW1 and SW2 close, dot-end of the primary gets more positive than its no-dot-end, so does of the secondary according to winding ratio, then DS1 conducts and DS2 cuts-off. Current is fed to load through LO and CO.

When switches open, de-magnetization current follows DP2->primary winding->DP1->Vbus path to reset the primary. No-dot-ends of the windings gets more positive than their dot-ends, so DS1 cuts-off. The energy stored in LO is transferred to the load by the help of DS2.

R201-R202-C202 and R203-R204-C203 are snubbers to protect secondary diodes.

As described above, there's a controlled switching action. There are square-wave-like signals across the primary and secondary of the transformer. So its quite normal to see both AC *(because they vary by the time)* and DC *(because they have a "mean" value)* at all the junctions before LO inductor *(Its named as L201 in your schematic)*. If enough filtering is not provided, you can even see "via an oscilloscope" both AC and DC at the output nodes.

Note that the switching frequency should be around a few tens of kHz, so some digital multimeters cannot measure the signals having that level of "high" frequencies correctly.

Sorry for crappy English. 
hth.

Comment: Thanks Rohat for a brief clarification to this question. As you said the signals would be square wave like and I could think that for this kind of waveforms Peak and DC should be same but in my case, Peak is 50V and mean value is 12.27Vdc. Can it be a possibility?Because I couldn't remember the exact wave shape.

Comment: If VDC is mean and Vpeak is the peak value of the pulsed signal then duty cycle would be Vmean/Vpk = 12.27/50 = %25 in your case --which is quite reasonable for an SMPS. If possible, change input voltage around %10 and measure that peak values. They should change within some possible limits. But please note that even true RMS multimeters are not designed to measure signals having a freq of tens of kHz. I personally recommend you to use an oscilloscope and upload some images here, this will help you (and us) a lot.

Comment: Hi Rohat, Actually I have measured through oscilloscope only and when I was getting the mean value to be 12.4V and to just confirmed once again I had used multimeter Fluke 107. I will upload some images also of the measurement for which I need some time.